Preferred way of configuration testing
I recently ran into a problem with configuration, caused by a malformed database path for a certain package. This causes a problem in emacsql-sqlite, because it tries to treat the folder name as a file, but the error message is not descriptive at all.
This leads to a more generic question of how exactly should the user configuration be validated, i.e. I can of course add a check command at the beginning of a package and it works fine, but I'm sure I'm not the first one who thinks about it and there is a more elegant/standard way of doing it and maybe some guidelines.
Current, not very informative error:
⛔ Error (use-package): org-roam/:init: EmacSQL had an unhandled condition: sqlitep, nil
A primitive check:
(if (file-directory-p org-roam-db-location) (error (format "org-roam-db-location %S should be file, not folder " org-roam-db-location)))


Unfortunately, this question is too generic and open-ended for this site. There are too many possibilities and any solution would contain a large component of personal opinion. I would recommend a discussion site (like reddit) or the gnu-emacs-help mailing list as proper places for discussion. Or you could report a bug (specific to the problem you encountered - not a generic discussion) to various places (e.g. org-roam and emacsql - both third-party packages) and see what they say.

@nickD Thanks, I was afraid it would be too generic. However, I wanted to avoid discussion sites for exactly the reason that I do not want discussion, but working examples of how things have been done before. Creating pull requests for this corner case for both org-roam and emacsql is not hard, but I think the problem is wider and I'd like to understand the mindset better. But, as you stated, this place is not suited for such tasks...

It's worth emphasising that "configuration" in Emacs is programming.  You're writing a software program in the Emacs Lisp language -- and one of the standard programming assumptions is that all software has bugs, which in turn tells us that there's no particularly straightforward way to avoid them.  (Proving the correctness of a program can be done mathematically, but it's not easy.)

@phils Agree, but I'm not concerned about configuration as a whole atm, just the unit level. I'm pretty sure having meaningful error messages at unit level will also make managing large configurations easier.

Meaningful error messages are of course desirable at any level but there is no generic mechanism to do that: when you find one that is not meaningful (and note that the meaning of "meaningful" will vary between different people), you report a bug on it. Even so, it might not be fixable, depending on how the software is structured. And it is even more difficult when many independent packages are involved. In some cases, it might be "better" to not catch the error and let Emacs generate a backtrace that shows how you got to the error.

But here we are having  a discussion :-) You really should take it to a discussion forum.

@NickD thanks for discussion, let's move to https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1e9s50w/preferred_way_of_configuration_validation/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

@phils let's move to reddit if you are interested in further discussion.
